# How to type text into a box I copied and placed onto a Master using InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, copy-and-paste

I want to update a "Master" using InDesign. Each time I copy a "Text Box" and "Paste" it onto the "Master," the copied Text Box does not allow new text to be entered AND the "Header" from the original text box disappears - how do I "copy" a text box from a Master and "Paste" it onto another section and have the box accept new text?

Answer (score 1):

For any object on a Master page (or 'Parent' page as recent versions of InDesign have started calling them), you can unlock it on any regular page by <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>ing it.